# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, syntax-error

I'm making a new jQuery plugin for drawing lines on a page.
The problem is that I can't figure out what's going on here, when I run the script, in Chrome it says:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"
```

on the 8th to last line (the one that reads: `$.line();`).

The whole code:

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.line = function(coordinates) {

        var bothpoints;

        $.fn.line.draw = function() {

            var lineColor = $('#lineRegion').attr('lineColor');

            if (!lineColor) {
                var colors = ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple', 'magenta', 'cyan'];

                $('img.line').each(function () {
                    colors.splice(colors.indexOf($(this).css('color')), 1);
                });

                var lineColor = colors[0];

            }

            var data = $.line.data(),
                width = Math.abs(data[0] - data[2]),
                height = Math.abs(data[1] - data[3]);
            if (data[0] >> data[2]) {
                var lineleft = data[2];
            } else {
                var lineleft = data[0];
            }
            if (data[1] >> data[3]) {
                var linetop = data[1];
            } else {
                var linetop = data[3];
            }

            $('body').append('<img class="line" src="/lines/line-'+lineColor+'.png" style="position:absolute;top:'+linetop+';left:'+lineleft+';width:'+width+'px;height:'+height+'px;color:'+lineColor+';"/>');
        }

        $.fn.line.data = function(coords) {
            if (coords.length == 2) {
                if ( ! $('#line').data('point1') ) { 
                    $('#line').data('point1', {x: coords[0], y: coords[1]});
                    bothpoints = false;
                } else {
                    $('#line').data('point2', {x: coords[0], y: coords[1]});
                    bothpoints = true;
                }
                $.line.draw();
            } else if (coords == 1) {
                $('#line').data('point1', false);
                bothpoints = false;
            } else if (coords == 2) {
                $('#line').data('point2', false);
                bothpoints = false;
            } else if (!coords) {
                return [$('#line').data('point1').x, $('#line').data('point1').y, $('#line').data('point2').x, $('#line').data('point2').y];
            }
        }

        $.fn.line.point = function() {
            if (!($.line.data().length == 4)) {
                var _posY = posy, _posX = posx;
                $('body').append('<div class="point" style="position:absolute; top:' + _posY + 'px; left:' + _posX + 'px;"></div>');
                $.line.data([_posX, _posY]);
                if (bothpoints == true) {
                    $.line.draw();
                }
            }
        }

        $.fn.line.unpoint = function() {
            this.hide('fast');
            if ($.line.data()[0] == this.offset()['left'] && $.line.data[1] == this.offset()['top']) {
                $.line.data(1);
            } else {
                $.line.data(2);
            }
            $.line.erase();
        }


        $.fn.line.erase = function(total) {
            if (total == true) {
                $('img.line').hide('fast');
                $('div.point').hide('fast');
                $.line.data(1);
                $.line.data(2);
            } else {
                $('img.line').hide('fast');
            }
        }

        if ( coordinates.length == 4) {
            $.line.data([coordinates[0], coordinates[1]]);
            $.line.data([coordinates[2], coordinates[3]]);
            $.line.draw();
        }

    };

    var posx, posy;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
            if (!e) var e = window.event;
            if (e.pageX || e.pageY)     {
                posx = e.pageX;
                posy = e.pageY;
            }
            else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
                posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
                    + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
                    + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            }
        }
        $.line();
        $('head').append('<meta id="line" />');
        $('#lineRegion').click( $.line.point() );
        $('.point').click( $.line.unpoint() );
        $('.lineEraser').click( $.line.erase(true) );
    }

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: To detect such simple coding errors try to use JSHint/JSLint. They usually provide more sensible error messages and make you embrace better coding practices.

Comment: @ssg - JSLint is too strict IMO, "Missing semicolon." `:/`

Comment: @Derek JSLint settings can be adjusted and JSHint is more down to earth than JSLint. However "missing semicolon" is important because "automatic semicolon insertion" in JavaScript can cause serious bugs without throwing an error when you miss one. I strongly suggest keeping that option on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You start an in-line function: `$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {` and never finish the statement after it. Before the line with the error, you need `});` instead of just `}`.

Comment: Sometimes it's as simple as that.  I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Now it's saying `"Unexpected token )"` on the last line

Comment: Looks like it's the same problem with the line before the last line.  You need to close the `document.ready` call.

Comment: @TLS - Now it says: `"Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'line'"`